# Publishing a npm module but it's not getting text predict (intellisense) when installed by users

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm currently working on my package @xatsuuc/startonomy.

For some reason, it's not getting intellisense when I'm installing it on user side. Below are my files. When I install the package and go to node_modules/@xatsuuc/startonomy it shows the .d.ts files but for some reason not a single bit of text predict works. Also, any suggestions for it? I don't know if I'm doing things right when compiling on the user's pc, or if I'm exporting modules correctly. Thanks in advance.

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [],
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./compiled",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "removeComments": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDirs": ["./src"],
    "types": ["@types/mysql", "@types/node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "@xatsuuc/startonomy",
  "version": "2.0.0-Gamma",
  "description": "A discord-based economy system",
  "main": "compiled/index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/xAtsuUC/Startonomy.git",
  "author": "Tiziano Fioretti <tiziafioretti@gmail.com>",
  "license": "CC BY-SA 4.0",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "files": [
    "src",
    "README.md",
    "tsconfig.json"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.26",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.30",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.25.12",
    "typedoc-material-theme": "^1.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/",
    "access": "public"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm i typescript",
    "install": "tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm uninstall typescript"
  }
}
```

GuildManager.ts

```
import { Pool, ConnectionConfig } from "mysql"
import { EventEmitter } from "node:events"
import Util from "./Util"

/**
 * Guild Manager
 * @class GuildManager
 * @extends EventEmitter
 * @param {ConnectionConfig} database - The database connection configuration
 * @example
 * const economy = new guildManager({
 *     host: "localhost",
 *     user: "root",
 *     password: "password",
 *     database: "database"
 * });
 */
class GuildManager extends EventEmitter {
    database: ConnectionConfig
    util: Util
    constructor(database: ConnectionConfig) {
        super()
        this.database = database
        this.util = new Util()
    }

    public test() {
        console.log("Test")
    }
}

export default GuildManager
```

index.ts

```
import GuildManager from "./GuildManager"
import Util from "./Util"

module.exports = { GuildManager, Util }
```

Comment: And yes, those anotations are typedoc (jsdoc for typescript) anotations

Comment: module.exports is an outdated format of exports, thought it still may provide type hints, I would not use it. I would do `export GuildManager  from "./GuildManager"; export Util from "./Util"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should define `types` in your package.json. for example:

```
{
 "types": "dist/index.d.ts", // change to your path of .d.ts
}
```